# Phonegap App opens url in browser. I want to open in app itself

Tags: cordova

I am new phone gap and i tries InAPP browser and its open the url in browser. Any fix to open  url in app itself ?.

window.open('http://myloginapp.com', '_blank', 'location=no');

Comment: are you testing it on a device?  have you installed the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Question isn't fully clear, but I'm giving a full answer.

Install [inAppBrowser Plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

This will open the link inside app.

```
 window.open('http://myloginapp.com', '_self', 'location=no');
```

This will open link in inAppBrowser view

```
window.open('http://myloginapp.com', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

This will open link in external native browser

```
window.open('http://myloginapp.com', '_system', 'location=no');
```